# How to show img in laravel app using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5

I am working in Laravel to print a badge and ticket. I have one problem. The image is not showing even if the link is correct, via Javascript, but if I added the same image directly in HTML then it works very well.

```js
function printdiv(divID) {
  var nom = document.getElementById('nom').value;
  var prenom = document.getElementById('prenom').value;
  var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
  @foreach($champs as $input)
  var {{ $input - > formInputs - > input }} = document.getElementById('{{  $input->formInputs->input }}').value;
  @endforeach

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo route('printform',['id'=> $id]) ?>",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      nom: nom,
      prenom: prenom,
      _token: token
      @foreach($champs as $input), 
        {{ $input - > formInputs - > input }}: {{ $input - > formInputs - > input }}
      @endforeach
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var qr = document.createElement("img");
      qr.src = "{{  url('/') }}/qrcodes/{{ Session::get('qrcode')}}";
      document.getElementById('imgq').appendChild(qr);

      $.post('', {
        "from": "HM43",
        "nom": nom,
        "prenom": prenom
      });

      document.all.item(divID).innerHTML = "<h2 style='text-align:center; font-size:50px'>  " + nom + " " + prenom + "<br> </h2>";
      @foreach($champs as $input)
        document.all.item(divID).innerHTML += "<h2 style='text-align:center; font-size:46px'> " + {{ $input - > formInputs - > input }} + "<br> </h2> ";
      @endforeach

      document.all.item(divID).innerHTML += "<img src='{{  url('/') }}/qrcodes/{{ Session::get('qrcode')}}' style='width:100PX' />";
      var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body  style='width: 350px'>";
      var footstr = "</body>";
      var newstr = document.all.item(divID).innerHTML;
      var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
      document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
      window.print();
      document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
      document.all.item(divID).innerHTML = "";
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Is the image URL properly generated in the JavaScript? Have you tried using the blade asset() helper instead of url()?

Comment: @ChadKieffer yes, but not working too ..

Comment: Is qr.src correct in the generated JavaScript source?

Comment: Yes because when I move it to html works and the picture appears

Comment: How are you injecting qr.src into the browser? I don't see how you're displaying qr.src into the #imgq element as there is no reference to imgq in the JS.

Comment: What's not clear is how you're adding the image. The "document.getElementById('imgq').appendChild(qr);" line is not sufficient on its own to add an img element.